# PayPal Express Checkout with Pay with my credit or debit card (Optional) Sign up

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using php to implement a PayPal Express Checkout as a payment method.

All I want for my users is their first option to be...

**Pay with my credit or debit card**
**(Optional) Sign up** for PayPal for faster future checkout

their second option should be...

Pay with my PayPal account
Log in to your PayPal account to complete the purchase

This is my form...

```
<form id="paypal_form" class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post">
  <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
  <input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input name="lc" type="hidden" value="GR" />
  <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR" />
  <input name="bn" type="hidden" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest" />
  <input name="item_number" type="hidden" value="1" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Payment with PayPal" />
</form>
```

I have already setup in my sandbox account

TYPE: BUSINESS
PayPal account's Profile -> More Options -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences -> PayPal Account Optional: ON

The result is that I get the screen...

**Create a PayPal account**
And pay with your debit or credit card

Any suggestions !?!?

Comment: Actually, to tell you the truth it works when I use the Opera browser and doesn't work with all the others (Firefox, IE 10, Google Chrome, Safari). Is that possible !?!? Check it out your self here... http://pp.my-soul.net/without-paypal-account/

Answer (score 2):

It works fine if you add these parameters when you call setExpressCheckout method:

```
<input type=hidden name=SOLUTIONTYPE value=Sole>
<input type=hidden name=LANDINGPAGE value=Billing>
```

Was hard to find but I found it here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_expresscheckout_advancedfeaturesguide.pdf

Hope it´s help!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are not seeing this show up is because PayPal account optional is not available for every coutntry, and select cross border transactions.  If you remove the following from being passed over in your code, you should see the same results in the browsers.

```
lc=GR
```

Comment: Actually I think it has to do with how each browser handle cookies, because when i cleared them... it worked!

Comment: First make sure in your Paypal/Sandbox account the PayPal Account have **Optional: ON** Go to --> PayPal account's Profile -> More Options -> My Selling Tools -> Website Preferences screen.
And then set **SolutionTypeType=Sole** while making request for setExpressCheckout this will enable the option to Pay with your debit or credit card. I think that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Add this simple input field to your Paypal Payment Form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="billing" name="landing_page">
```

Its fine works for me.

You can check Complete Paypal Payment Form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="yourbusinesspaypalaccountemail@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" value="billing" name="landing_page"> <!-- This filed redirect to Billing Page -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Item Name">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="YOUR TOTAL AMOUNT">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="Your Success URL">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="Your Cancel Return URL">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.yourdomain.com/images/paypalpaynowbtn.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```